# Поведение терминала как в manjaro xfce

Tags: manjaro, kde

Дело простое. В Manjaro XFCE терминал открывается клавишами CTRL+ALT+T, но если нажать еще раз то терминал сворачивается и можно также быстро открыть на том же месте теми же клавишами. Я очень к этому привык, это очень удобно. Сейчас поставил Manjaro Plasma и в нем такое фишки нет. Возможно ли реализовать такую фишку тут или поставить обратно XFCE? (к сожалению я в линуксе не сильно  шарю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в XFCE по умолчанию идёт [xfce4-terminal](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/xfce4-terminal/) который естественно можно установить и в KDE, если делать установку из терминала то :

```
sudo pacman -S xfce4-terminal
```

для запуска которого в режиме **drop down** нужно запускать с ключом:

```
xfce4-terminal --drop-down
```

комбинация клавиш для запуска/скрытия устанавливается в настройках самой графической оболочки(XFCE, GNOME, KDE ...), для **XFCE** у **manjaro** даная комбинация уже прописанна по умолчанию и задана как **Ctrl+Alt+T** (при желании можно задать свою), для **KDE** комбинацию нужно прописывать самому.

п.с.

естественно терминалов умеющих в **drop down** хватает, к примеру, та же [tilda](https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=tilda), [yakuake](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/yakuake/) ...

Answer (score 0):

Для таких как я оставлю ответ. Фишка эта гуглиться как "dropdown terminal" и их там целая куча на вкус и цвет. В Manjaro kde plasma оказывается уже есть yakuake, открывается на F12.